# Loading JS files in CakePHP 3

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a template inside a plugin in my project, that is trying to load a "general" JS file:

```
<?= $this->Html->script([
    'base.js',
], [
    'fullBase' => true,
]) ?>
```

`public/` is the root folder of the whole project, and the `bootstrap.ctp` template file resides inside the plugin folder:

```
/var/www/repo/publi/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Template/Layout/bootstrap.ctp
```

while the `base.js` file resides in the "general" webroot folder:

```
/var/www/repo/public/webroot/js/base.js
```

When I visit the page, this is the error I get:

```
GET https://localhost/var/www/repo/public/js/base.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the output of the `$this->Html->script()` call:

```
<script src="/var/www/repo/public/js/webroot/base.js"></script>
```

And this is the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I add

```
dd(WWW_ROOT);
```

at the beginning of my template file, I get the correct output with the path that I would expect:

```
/var/www/repo/public/webroot/
```

So, my question is: if the `WWW_ROOT` constant is correctly configured, why is the `script()` function loading the `base.js` file incorrectly?

[CakePHP's own documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-javascript-files) even states that

> This method of JavaScript file inclusion assumes that the JavaScript file specified resides inside the webroot/js directory:

which is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Do you have a `baseUrl` or `fullBaseUrl` specified anywhere in your config?

Comment: No I don't. Or, to be more precise, the `baseUrl` line is commented and the `fullBaseUrl` is set to `false` in the app.php config file. Should I change that? Or do I have something wrong in my `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No, that should be fine. Can you show exactly what HTML is output from your `$this->Html->script` call? Try it without the `fullBase` option and show that HTML too?

Comment: I'm guessing the only reason you're using fullBase here is due to something akin to a template for emails? Otherwise you wouldn't need that.